# java ant compile does not find class in same directory in same package

Tags: java, ant, compiler-errors

I try to compile with ant via cmd a JUnit/Selenium test. I cannot use eclipse, bc it has broken Intellisense.
I added a "AssertionCustomException" public class with same filename in same directory and same package:

```
package de.auticon.zeiterfassung;
/**
 * My custom exception class.
 */
public class AssertionCustomException extends Exception
{
   //Parameterless Constructor
      public AssertionCustomException() {}


  public AssertionCustomException(String message)
  {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

but the throw command:

```
if (error){
            throw AssertionCustomException;
        } else {


            try {
                className = "has-error";
                input = driver.findElement(By.className(className));
                result = input.isDisplayed();
                System.out.println("Page contains error: " + result);

                assertTrue("Error: displayed", result);
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                fail("No Error message");
            }

        }
```

gives an error:

```
[javac] C:\Source\workspace4\ahub\src\de\auticon\zeiterfassung\Test_enter_day.java:247: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]                             throw AssertionCustomException;
[javac]                                   ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable AssertionCustomException
[javac]   location: class Test_enter_day
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You need to throw an instance of the class, e.g `throw new AssertionCustomException();`

Comment: Thanks, I found it, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We added `throw new AssertionCustomException();`, thanks to Jameson for giving the right answer!